# ROS2 QoS callback function

Tags: ros, ros2, c++, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

First of all, I just learned about ROS2 so I am not so familiar with it. Also, I apologize for my bad English.

I am now working on how to implement QoS in my subscription. I have a little bit experience on eProsima FastRTPS and I did manage to run publisher and subscriber with QoS policies. Thus, I expected ROS2 works quite the same way. Here I want to have a deadline policy with a callback function. However, I were lost while trying to set up the callback because in FastRTPS, it has publisher/subscriber listener, which handles all the event callback functions. In ROS2, I do not know where and how to put or configure callback function. I had a look in `SubscriptionEventCallbacks` class but it did not work (maybe I set it wrongly). After searching on internet, I have not had any clue yet.

Below is a part of my code trying to configure QoS (I am also not expert on C++ and I am learning it, so feel free to put any comment):

```
Listener(): Node("Listener_node") // Constructor
{
rclcpp::QoS qos_profile(10);
std::chrono::milliseconds deadline_time(1000);
qos_profile.deadline(deadline_time);
Subscription = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic",qos_profile,std::bind(&Listener::callback,this,std::placeholder::_1));
}
```

Any recommendation, comment or hint is welcomed!

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/345018/ros2-qos-callback-function/) by [Sapodilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/46788/sapodilla/) on ROS Answers with karma: 48 on 2020-02-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-02-25**:
Can you concisely state what your issue is? Your code sample below looks very reasonable.

**Comment by [Sapodilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/46788/sapodilla/) on 2020-02-26**:
Hi Steven, sorry for my late response. I already found the solution for my issue a few second before typing this comment :D. To make it a bit more clearly, I want to have a callback function whenever a deadline is missed. After spending some time to going through [ROS2 doxygen](https://docs.ros2.org/eloquent/api/rclcpp/index.html), it finally works for me :). I will put the answer for those who come across this problem like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To whoever struggles the same problem as me, for having your callback function for QoS, specify the callback function in `rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions`.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Sapodilla](https://answers.ros.org/users/46788/sapodilla/) with karma: 48 on 2020-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gunika](https://answers.ros.org/users/65874/gunika/) on 2020-12-18**:
Hello Can you let me know how did you use rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions in the code?

**Comment by [Gunika](https://answers.ros.org/users/65874/gunika/) on 2020-12-19**:
Can you please let me know how did you use the callback in rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions?
This is my code for the **subscriber**:
rclcpp::QoS qos_profile(10);
std::chrono::milliseconds deadline_time(1000);
qos_profile.deadline(deadline_time);
rclcpp::SubscriptionOptions subscription_options;
subscription_options.event_callbacks.deadline_callback =
[](rclcpp::QOSDeadlineRequestedInfo & event) -> void
{
std::cout << "Connection Lost";
};

```
  subscription_ = this->create_subscription<std_msgs::msg::String>(
  "topic", 10,subscription_options,qos_profile,std::bind(&MinimalSubscriber::topic_callback, this, _1));
}
```

**Publisher:**
{
rclcpp::QoS qos_profile(10);
std::chrono::milliseconds deadline_time(1000);
qos_profile.deadline(deadline_time);
publisher_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10,qos_profile);
timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(
500ms, std::bind(&MinimalPublisher::t